# JavaScript - how to make wait animation show before the rest of data is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

In my application I have a subpage, where I load some data from API call (using synchronous XMLHttpRequest).
I thought it would be nice to show user waiting animation, while data is not ready.

I wanted to achieve this in a simple way, just by taking div and setting its content with HTML img element and then hide it, when other div will be filled with data.
I've tried following approaches:

```
<div style="width: 100%;" id="test"></div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
        <canvas id="sent"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
        <canvas id="delivered"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
        <canvas id="changed"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    waitDiv('test');
    loadDataFromAPI();
</script>
```

`waitDiv()` function just grabs element by id and replaces its inner HTML.
The above code doesn't work as I expect to.
After removing from `loadDataFromAPI()` line in which `'test'` div is hidden, I've observed that loading image is being visible at the exact moment when the rest of data is being shown.
When I tried to debug it and stopped right after `waitDiv()`, I've found out that the div `'test'` has an image inside, but its size is 0, despite that its width and height properties are set.

I have also tried to make `loadDataFromAPI()` a callback function. Then my code looks like:

```
<script>
    loadData(loadDataFromAPI());
</script>
```

and in Javascript file

```
function loadData(_callback) {
    waitDiv('test');

    if (typeof _callback === 'function')
        _callback();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work either.

So going to conclusions:

1) I am quite new to JavaScript and just don't quite understand its behaviour. I was expecting code to execute line-by-line.
`waitDiv();` >> visible result >> `loadDataFromAPI();` >> visible result. Could someone give an explanation, why my code doesn't work like that and how does it actually work?

2) How should I fix my code to meet my expectations?

I would be grateful for any help or hint.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you post all the relevant part of your code so that we can build a working example from what you already tried? The API calls can be easily faked with sample data and timeouts.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `jQuery.ajax()` in the jQuery library. You show the waiting UI before calling the ajax() and then in its complete function, you hide the waiting UI.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I have solved the problem by wrapping function ```loadDataFromAPI()``` in ```setTimeout()```. If I find a little bit of time I would try to create a code snippet, which would recreate my original issue. It will still be good to know what's the cause of such behaviour and how to fix it, since solution which I provided is more like a trick than a real solution.